# Why do my embedded css-fonts arent working?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have 2 fonts on my website and the fonts were displaying correctly. I updated my Firefox Browser(i think this was the problem)(version 68) but now they aren't working anymore. Beside the fallback font aren't working as well.

My css file is excluded and every other styles are working.

I tried the !important tag, and different styles of that font.

My operating system is linux mint. I tried it on Windows 10 and the fallback font is wroking but the other fonts not.

The linking of foler is also working correctly bec it also worked earlier.

My css is extern but all the other rules are working.

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
<style>
@font-face { font-family: 'Tangerine';
             src: url('tangerine/Tangerine_Bold.ttf') format('truetype'); }

@font-face { font-family: 'Odstemplik';
             src: url('odstemplik/odstemplikReg.otf');}
h1{
font-family:'Odstemplik', cursive;
}
h2{
font-family:'Tangerine', cursive;
}
</style>
```

The fonts should working correctly. But it looks they don't want :)

Comment: have you tried to put your style tag before the h1 and h2 elements ?

Comment: Yes, it is in an extern css file.

Comment: Try using an absolute path to the .ttf and .otf files. That can be tricky to deal with when the CSS is in an external file.